# ETH Sent to Uniswap V2 router after creating LP

Tags: uniswap, arbitrum, uniswapv2, router, pairings

Please help. I tried creating an LP on Uniswap V2 on Arbitrum. It turns out only v3 is available on arb one.

On uniswap page, I chose v2 pool on Eth network, then on top right, I changed it to Arb one. I provided .25 eth with my test tokens.

This is the txn:
0xd4766f69a13480d3f08238d36e48861778707fe67d282ffb9900f630cd58a302

[image]

I'm lost on how I can retrieve this eth. Would really need help on this.